# Distribution of $Y$ when, $Z = Y \times X$, $X \sim Poisson(\lambda_x)$ and $Z \sim Poisson(\lambda_z)$

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution

Is there any know distribution such that when a random variable from it is multiplied with an IID random variable from a Poisson distribution, it results in a Poisson distributed random variable? Clearly, it will be a ratio of Poisson distributions, but is there a standard distribution for that?

Comment: Consider (among other issues) that the denominator of your ratio of Poissons can always take the value 0.

Answer (score 4):

For $\lambda_x=\lambda_z$ it's trivially possible: $Y=1$.

Suppose $\lambda_z>\lambda_x$. In that case $P(Z=0)<P(X=0)$. But $X=0$ implies $Z=0$, so that's impossible.

It's more complicated if $\lambda_z<\lambda_x$.

We know that $Y$ must take non-negative integer values, since otherwise $Z$ wouldn't be non-negative integers.

Consider $E[Z|Z>0]$ and $E[X|X>0]$.  If $Y$ takes on values greater than 1, then
$$E[Z|Z>0]=E[XY|X>0 \cap Y>0]>E[X|X>0 \cap Y>0]=E[X|X>0]$$
But that isn't true for Poisson with $\lambda_z<\lambda_x$, so we get a contradiction.

So $Y$ must be binary 0/1, making it Bernoulli(p) for some $p$. To have $E[Z]=E[Y]E[X]$ we need $p=\lambda_z/\lambda_x$. But then $$P(Z>0)=P(X>0)P(Y>0)$$
so
$$1-\exp(-\lambda_z)=(1-\exp(-\lambda_x))\frac{\lambda_z}{\lambda_x}$$
so
$$\frac{1-\exp(-\lambda_z)}{1-\exp(-\lambda_x)}=\frac{\lambda_z}{\lambda_x}$$
which will not be true in general.

It's not possible, except perhaps for a few special values of $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_z$